# Threads. Stopping Server

Tags: java, multithreading, server

Recently I was doing multithreaded chat application. Now I am struggling with server. I am trying to stop the server by introducing new field `online`, but it doesn't help.

```
import view.ChatHub;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ChatServer extends Thread {
    // All client names, so we can check for duplicates upon registration.
    private static Set<String> names = new HashSet<>();
    // The set of all the print writers for all the clients, used for broadcast.
    private static Set<PrintWriter> writers = new HashSet<>();
    private ChatHub frame;
    private int port;
    private boolean online;
    private ExecutorService pool;

    public ChatServer(int port) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("The chat server is running...");
        this.frame = new ChatHub(this);
        this.port = port;
        this.online = true;
        this.pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (this.online) {
            try (ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(this.port)) {
                this.pool.execute(new Handler(listener.accept(), this.names, this.writers));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopChatServer() {
        this.pool.shutdown();
        this.online = false;
    }


    public Set<String> getNames() {
        return this.names;
    }

    public Set<PrintWriter> getWriters() {
        return this.getWriters();
    }

    public ChatHub getFrame() {
        return this.frame;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.port;
    }

}
```

Here I am trying to close the server:

```
import Client.ChatClient;
import Server.ChatServer;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;


public class ChatHub extends JFrame{
    JTextField textField;
    JTextArea messageArea;

    public ChatHub(ChatServer server) {
        new JFrame("Chatter");
        this.textField = new JTextField(50);
        this.messageArea = new JTextArea(16,50);
        this.textField.setEditable(true);
        this.messageArea.setEditable(false);
        this.getContentPane().add(this.textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(this.messageArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.pack();
//        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                server.stopChatServer();
            }
        });
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void appendMessage(String line) {
        messageArea.append(line + "\n");
    }

    public JTextField getTextField() {
        return this.textField;
    }

    public JTextArea getMessageArea() {
        return this.messageArea;
    }

    public void nameAccepted(String line) {
        this.setTitle("Chatter - " + line.substring(13));
        textField.setEditable(true);
    }


}
```

Also I tried to have method `run` with while just printing some `String`. But when it left `run` method the program was still working. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Also I tried to implement `run()` as the following:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        while (this.online) {
            System.out.println("Some String");
        }
        System.out.println(this.isAlive() + "\n");
    }
```

And it does output `true` in the end.

Comment: i cant see where you stop the server. looks like you do not run stopChatServer()

Comment: You're probably blocking on `listener.accept()`, so you don't get to the while loop condition.

Comment: Line `this.pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500);` creates executor service that server uses to execute code that handles incoming connections. So, when you stop server in `stopChatServer()` method you have to terminate executor service calling `shutdown()` method. Refer to Java documentation of [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for more details.

Comment: Also, make sure you create Daemon threads in your threadpool (need a custom ThreadFactory for that) otherwise the default is User threads that stay alive and won't let you shutdown your server.

Comment: I added to the method ```stopChatServer()```  ```this.pool.shutdown()```, but it is not working.

Comment: If I am running class without ```Pool```, it is still cannot terminate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have another problem here (Swing Related):

1. Your `new JFrame("Chatter")` just creates a new JFrame and does nothing with it. You have to call `super("Chatter");` to call the super constructor
2. Try

   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to declare your `online` property as `volatile`?

```
private volatile boolean online = true;
```

If you do not declare a property as `volatile`, the JIT compiler can assume that your boolean property will not be changed by another thread. So it may optimize your run method to

```
public void run() {
    if (!online)
        return;
    while(true) {
        try(/*...*/) {
           // ...
        } catch(/*...*/) {
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the ```while```-loop terminates, but it does not finish the program

Comment: "If you do not declare a property as volatile, the JVM assumes that your boolean property can not be changed by another thread and is not altered at all" this is a wrong statement! 'volatile' is about visibility not about blocking for writing. 'private volatile boolean online = true;' will guarantee that other thread will see current state of boolean if another thread changes it

Comment: @Vault23 You're right; I 'shortened' it a bit in the wrong way an updated my post. I hope it is no longer wrong now.